# Mongodb find query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have requirement like I need to search the fields which are dynamic in collection.
Example as shown below in one collection I want to search for title="Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800" but title will be changes from document to document.

First document title refers to "xyz" which is title for that document.
Second document title refers to "abc" which is title for that document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b988de0be31724e"),     
    "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "xyz"        
    },
   "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b9435dfgdf43554b"),     
    "abc" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "abc"        
    }
}
```

Please suggest me  query to produce result as expected above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get a distinct list of all the `mappingData` titles, you can do that using the **[`distinct(`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct)**) method on the collection. With that list you can then construct the query object to use in the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** method. Ideally you would need the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator in your find query. Normally, your find query would resemble:

```
db.collection.find({
    "$or": [
        { "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800" },
        { "abc" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800" }
    ]
})
```

So you need a mechanism to generate the above query and the following example demonstrates this approach:

```
var titles = db.collection.distinct("mappingData.title"),
    titleVal = "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    query = { "$or": [] };

query["$or"] = titles.map(function (t){
    var q = {};
    q[t] = titleVal;
    return q;
});

db.collection.find(query);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56543f577d3c273d063cd226"),
    "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {
        "title" : "xyz"
    }
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56543f577d3c273d063cd227"),
    "abc" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {
        "title" : "abc"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks chridam. I tried your query but it is returning  error as shown below.

error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array",
 "code" : 17287
}

Comment: When you run `db.collection.distinct("mappingData.title")` what do you get, of course substituting collection with your actual collection name?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake. Now it working but not as I expected.
will this work for even for one mapping data also like

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b988de0be31724e"),     
    "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "xyz"        
    },
   "_id" : ObjectId("5640bdec1b9435dfgdf43554b"),     
    "xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "mappingData" : {       
        "title" : "xyz"        
    }
}

Comment: Thanks it's working fine . I have 10 million data and  it is taking too much time to  execute. Could suggest me how I can speed up this.

Comment: If this has answered your question please consider [**marking the answer as accepted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Looks like the original problem [Mongodb find query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891341/mongodb-find-query) is solved isn't it? As for the performance issue, that would be a **[different question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome")**, consider posting it separately.

Answer (score -1):

```
/** search query */
exports.search = function(req, res) {
    var query = {};   
    for(var key in req.body){
      query[key] = req.body[key];
    }
    Collection.find(query)
    .exec(function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
              console.log(result);
            }
        }
        else {
             console.log(err);
        }
    });
};
```

In this situation, you don't need to make your query static, whatever is coming from froented just use key and value and filter the data.
Hope it works for you.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: I am not sure how exactly I can use it for my scenario. could you explain me with my use case  ?

Comment: You can just pass the data in req.body like
{
"xyz" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800"
}